# Copy self-created folders from Thunderbird Windows to Thunderbird Ubuntu

Tags: email, thunderbird

I used the instructions at https://superuser.com/questions/1550634/moving-thunderbird-email-setup-from-win10-to-linux-ubuntu to migrate from Thunderbird in Win10 to Ubuntu 20. Only the standard (Inbox, Sent, etc) emails were migrated.

I have several folders containing important emails I don't want to lose but these didn't migrate. How can I copy them over?

Alan

Comment: I used to export the mails to mbox format in windows and import them into Ubuntu. Is that no longer possible?

Comment: What was the "base folder" of the folders that did not move? Were they under Local Folders, or under an email account? If they were under an email account, is the account IMAP or POP?

Comment: They are under an IMAP email account .